# Just Get Newly added Child Firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to get reference or snapshot of newly added child on firebase 
i have solve it by different way

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                       }
```

```
myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s)
 {

                        }
```

My question is that both are return a complete snapshot means all this nodes in firebase is there any way getting child which newly added  ("this will improve speed")

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. You're new here so your question has been flagged for review. It looks like a good start. It would be better if you tidied up the code a bit (we don't need the @Override, bring in the indentation to 2 spaces, remember to close braces, etc. What we really want is a [mcve] of your problem. Remember, try to make it easy for people to help you, and the stuff you put here is intended to help others too, so keep in mind that other people with the same problem may be helped by the answers you receive, so try to remember the legacy of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attach a listener to a location or a query, the listener will initially fire with all data that exists at that location or that matches the query. The database has no concept of "new" data, although your application may have that concept.

There are a few options to reduce the data that is retrieved, or the data that is passed to your listener:

1. If you're [using disk persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence), the application may have a previous snapshot of the data in its disk cache. In that case, only the delta between the previous snapshot and the current snapshot is retrieved from the server. But the entire current snapshot is passed to your listener, so that you can render the UI correctly for the while current data.
2. If you only want to process the data since a certain moment, you'll need to only request that data from the database. You can typically do this by storing the key of the data you last processed in your local state, and then using a query like this to only get the new update:

   ```
   myRef.orderByKey().startAt("mostRecentKeyWeHaveAlreadyProcessed").add...Listener
   ```